# Is $scope a normal function parameter or something special?

Tags: angularjs

I'm a total beginner with Angular. I was looking at the w3schools tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

And I tried to change

```js
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

to

```js
app.controller('myCtrl', function(a) {
    a.firstName = "John";
    a.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

And the example stopped working. It seems like $scope isn't just a regular function parameter, but then what is it?

Comment: very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360295/what-is-scope-is-angularjs

Comment: Yes, `$scope` is a special parameter and, at least while starting out, one of the primary building blocks of Angular.  I also suggest not learning from w3schools.  A good starting place would be [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/articles/new-to-angularjs-start-learning-here)

Comment: I understand what the purpose of scope is, what I don't get is how does Javascript allow such odd behaviour for a function parameter?

Comment: Angular inspects the argument names to determine what to inject for each parameter. So changing its name means Angular no longer knows what to inject. Check out the answer from @tommy for an example of how to manually inject dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the name of parameters, but you need to use the following syntax notation:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(a) {
    a.firstName = "John";
    a.lastName = "Doe";
});

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function(a) {
    a.firstName = "John";
    a.lastName = "Doe";
}]);
```

Take a look to [DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: So Angular does some reflection on these methods, and that's why the parameter names matter, right?

Comment: It uses the first arguments as the real names of function's parameters. This is necessary because without this syntax, the minification process would break the application.