# What is props in ReactJS, Is it the same $scope of angular?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is props in ReactJS? Is it the same $scope of AngularJS? I can't seem to understand props in react, since im new to it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not equivalent:

- React `props` are input values which are passed into components to help describe its output.
- Angular `$scope` is an object that refers to the contextual execution (the scope) for an expression.
  *[[Check out this SO answer for 'What is $scope in angular?']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360295/what-is-scope-in-angularjs)*

Angular `$scope` is a object that ***defines the context*** of variables/properties/functions of a controller object.
React `props` are the ***actual the arbitrary values*** consumed by a component function/class.

---

*[React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)*:

> "*Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept
>   arbitrary inputs (called "props") and return React elements describing
>   what should appear on the screen.*"

*[Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)*:

> "*Scope is an object that refers to the application model. It is an
>   execution context for expressions.*"